# setTimeZone() in not working in android 9 (API 28)

Tags: java, android, permissions

I want to setTimeZone() for my system application. It works well in device Android 4.2 (API 17). But when I migrate to device Android 9 (API 28), I get the wrong message:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 11029 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE
```

I have added these permissions, but nothing happens.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" android:protectionLevel="signature|system"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

Here is my code:

```
public void setTimeZone(String timeZone) {
  ((AlarmManager) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE))
      .setTimeZone(timeZone);
}
```

I want to keep this functionality, what's your advice what should I use instead of AlarmManager.setTimeZone() method to change system time?

Comment: "I have added this permissions, but nothing happens" -- `android:protectionLevel` does not go in a `<uses-permission>` element. Your system app needs to be signed by the firmware signing key or it needs to be installed on the privileged partition.

Comment: Next to the cause is my application does not have the correct partition installed. Are there any other possible causes this problem?

Comment: You might want to contact the maintainers of the firmware and ask them for advice related to this specific environment.

Comment: Is there any other way that i can change the TimeZone of the system to the specific city?